# create google contact without duplicating them

Tags: google-contacts-api

I am trying to create a google contact using google contact API and got success in it by using this link https://developers.google.com/contacts/v3/#creating_contacts
But when I again creating the same contact it is not checking that it already exists and it is, therefore, creating duplicate contact in Gmail.i do not want to create duplicate contact if email id already exists in Gmail contacts.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, upon checking the documentation, there's no information regarding the duplication of contacts using Google Contacts API. There are two options you can use: first is to use Google Apps Script - [Duplicate check while creating Google Contact with Google Apps Script](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/48513/duplicate-check-while-creating-google-contact-with-google-apps-script) or by [manually removing the contacts in the UI](http://blog.evercontact.com/how-to-remove-duplicate-contacts-gmail-google-contacts/).